# Ionic Menu Drawer - how to disable for specific controller/state

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Menu Drawer (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-ion-drawer). It works fine in general, but I want to disable it for some controllers/states.

This is how I use an drawer:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content>

 <drawer side="left" ng-hide="disableDrawer">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">
      <h1 class="title" ng-bind="'Account: '+account"></h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

     <ion-content has-bouncing="false">
         <ion-list>
         </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</drawer>
```

As you can see, I've added `ng-hide="disableDrawer"` attribute to the drawer directive. In my controller I set `$rootScope.disableDrawer` to true and it hides the drawer menu itself, but there still is an background overlay div when I drag from left side. Any idea how can I completely hide the drawer with background layer?

Comment: If any fiddle or codepen, It would be clear and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in  `ng-hide="disableDrawer"` in  `<ion-side-menus>` as  well

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true" ng-hide="disableDrawer">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content>
```

Comment: This hides menus and content, which causes screen to be blank (because I fill my content in <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>).